# Property List Editor after installing Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode4, plist

I cannot find where it is after I installing Xcode 4. Does any one know where it is ?

Edit:

I had installed another app for editing XML file. It is named `XMLEditor` and located [here](http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/download.shtml). Because I need to edit a plist file with an extension which is not end with `.plist`, so finally I googled another solutions about `XML` editor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In XCode 4 the property list editor is integrated. It should appear in the XCode application.

Comment: if you right-click a plist file from within the XCode editor you can "Open as" to use other editors.

Comment: I need Property List Editor to browse a XML file. But the extension of file is not .xml .  I opened the file by xCode 4, but the behavior is not what I desire.

Comment: I changed the extension of file to .xml, and opened it by xCode4. It showed me the plain text format of xml.

Comment: Ok, after changing the extension to .plist and opening by xCode4, it finally give me what I want. Thank you for help. :)

Comment: Is the Property List Editor removed from Xcode ToolsSet? I got it on my two years old mac but now I installed a brand new Mac where I installed directly Xcode 4.0.2 but I can't find Property List Editor :( Ok I can use Xcode directly to edit plist but Property List Editor was also really confortable.

Comment: @Gabriele I think it's gone from Apple's tools. (I miss it too.) There is a third party app that looks pretty decent: [PlistEdit Pro](http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/plisteditpro/) if you're into that sort of thing.

Comment: PlistEdit would be an option except its a bit pricey for what it does. See the post from Richard H below, you can get the old app back (I'm running it on Mt Lion now).

Answer (score 5):

I put together a frankenstien version of the Property List Editor a while ago. Its totally self contained and should work as a stand alone app.

Find it here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k6knivza9dramb5/Stand%20Alone%20Property%20List%20Editor.app.zip

Comment: I wish I could give you 5 up arrows for this! So running this under Mt Lion does not work directly. Show package contents, remove the coderesources link and folder, open Sys Prefs, Security Privacy, allow apps from anywhere, run the app once,  then switch the security back, and all is well. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found in xcode 4 when you create a new plist file, the editor opens as blank.  If you right click in the blank editor space, you can "add row".  Begin from there.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I'd seen this before installing Xcode 4 - the Property List Editor.app was so nice and lightweight and fast - now having to launch Xcode.app just to edit a plist file ... ugh.

I'm going to dig it back out of my old Xcode 3 DMG ... this is just not cool.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Snow Leopard Property List Editor application on Mac OS X 10.7 Lion by following this tutorial:

http://sveinbjorn.org/install_property_list_editor_app_on_mac_os_x_lion

The application continues to work just fine in Lion, as long as you also install the now-deprecated framework it relies on.  It's just that Apple isn't including it, presumably because they want us to use bloated XCode 4.